# Pass a readable JSON as string into Nomad Template

Tags: nomad, consul-template

We are using nomad template to add environment variables for our nomad deployments.

```
      template {
  data = <<EOH
Key1=value1
Key2=value2
Key3=AJsonstring
EOH

  change_mode = "restart"
  destination = "environments/file.env"
  env         = true
}
```

I notice that nomad requires me to escape my JSON string in order for me to properly pass it in.
Ie: say i want to pass in `{"a":3,"b":4}` in Key3
I cannot just write it as is, instead, i had to write `"{\"a\":3,\"b\":4}"` which is a lot less readable.

Is there a way so I can just pass the plain string in and make it to interprets it as is?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using single quotes around your JSON object: `key3='{"a": 3, "b": 4 }'`.

```
$ echo {"a": 1}
{a: 1}
$ echo '{"a": 1}'
{"a": 1}
```

note: I haven't tested this! Just a guess based on how I'd expect things are put together.